# Expandable cell with firebase database?

Tags: swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to swift and I've been watching so many tutorials and looking at other peoples code to see how I can create a expandable cell in my table view controller. But, i've already created a  firebase database in the same view controller. The problem is, is that I need the information from my database to be in the expandable view cell with the exception of one label. Does anybody know how i can do this? (It'll make a bit more sense when you take a look at the code below)

```
   //
//  Database.swift
//  intern
//
//  Created by Lani  Daniels on 8/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Lani  Daniels. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct PostStruct {
        let title: String
        let message: String // How would I put this in the expandable cell?
        let company: String // ...Also this in the expandable cell, but i assume it would be the same method as "let message"

    }



class DatabaseViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    var posts: [PostStruct] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let title = snapshotValue?["title"] as? String

            let message = snapshotValue?["message"] as? String

            let company = snapshotValue?["company"] as? String

            self.posts.insert(PostStruct(title: title ?? "", message: message ?? "", company: company ?? ""), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        post()
    }
    func post(){

        let title = "Title"
        let message = "Message"
        let company = "Company"

        let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title" : title as AnyObject, "message" : message as AnyObject, "company" : company as AnyObject]

         let databaseRef  = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let label3 = cell.viewWithTag(3)as? UILabel; label3?.text=posts[indexPath.row].title
        label3?.text=posts[indexPath.row].title

        let textView2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextView; textView2?.text=posts[indexPath.row].message
        textView2?.text=posts[indexPath.row].message

        let label4 = cell.viewWithTag(4)as? UILabel; label4?.text=posts[indexPath.row].company
        label4?.text=posts[indexPath.row].company

        return cell
    }
    @IBAction func appliedDataTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey, so I'm not really clear what you want to achieve here.. But the process should be as follows: 

- Request your data from firebase
- Put that data in an Array
- Present data in cell

Comment: I just want to expand my table view cells when you click them @JArango